# Error when trying to map array.... Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been trying to understand WHY I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` when trying to map `this.state.forecastData`.. I have been fiddling around and trying different things, but i dont get it to map.

Can someone point me in the right direction and describe what I am doing wrong? (Im in the learning stages of ReactJS)

i can `console.log(res)` then i get this in the console:
[image]

**Here is my Component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
var queryString = require('query-string');
var api = require('../utils/api');

class Forecast extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            forecastData: [],
            loading: false
        }

        this.makeRequest = this.makeRequest.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        this.city = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search).city;
        this.makeRequest(this.city);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.city = queryString.parse(nextProps.location.search).city;
        this.makeRequest(this.city);
    }

    makeRequest (city) {
        this.setState(function () {
            return {
                loading: true,
            }
        })

        api.getCurrentWeather(city)
      .then(function (res) {
                console.log(res)
                this.setState(function () {
                    return {
                        forecastData: res,
                        loading: false,
                    }
                })
            }.bind(this))
    }

    render() {
    return this.state.loading === true
      ? <h1 className='forecast-header'> Loading </h1>
      : <div>
                    <h1 className='forecast-header'>{this.city}</h1>
                    <div className='forecast-container'>
                        {this.state.forecastData.list.map(function (listItem) {
                            return <div>Test</div>
                        }, this)}
                    </div>
                </div>
     }
}

export default Forecast;
```

Comment: In the code you pasted you are using `this.state.forecastData.list.map`, whick means you are trying to access a `list` property on the `forecastData` array (which is not there, of course)

Comment: Could you please post the data you are receiving in "res" parameter?

Comment: There's a [lots of posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=react+Cannot+read+property+%27map%27+of+undefined) regarding this issue and you din't find any?

Comment: Your forcastData is an object instead of Array (after analysing the response you have shared). You cannot use `map` function to iterate over such object. Recommended way is to model this response in your code and create a componnet which can render this type of response.

Answer (score 0):

```
{this.state.forecastData.list.map(function (listItem) {
                        return <div>Test</div>
                    }, this)}
```

should be

```
{this.state.forecastData.map(function (listItem) {
                            return <div>Test</div>
                        }, this)}
```

since you are accessing `list` of `forecastData`, but `forecastData` is already an array you can map.

Comment: Tested your soloution but then i get TypeError: this.state.forecastData.map is not a function

Comment: It's because when you're assigning `forecastData` to `res`, `res` is an object and you can't `map` over it. You'll need to have an array of forecastData, but it looks like you're just pulling one forecast.